# How to execute code loaded into memory from char* buffer?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, memory

I'm attempting to extract a couple of functions from our codebase so that they can instead be stored encrypted in `.text`, then only be decrypted and accessed with the correct license key. To do this we need to (1) extract the functions, (2) load the functions and (3) execute the functions successfully.

To extract the functions we're relying on `gcc` placing functions after each other which seems to work, since `FUNCTION_LENGTH` seems to result in the correct lengths. But so far I've been unable to load functions and execute them successfully, I'm getting a segmentation fault with no understandable information.

How can I execute code that has been loaded into memory from a `char* buffer`?

**example.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _FNAME_CAT(name, suffix) name##suffix
#define FNAME_CAT(name, suffix) _FNAME_CAT(name, suffix)

#define FUNCTION_START(ftype, fname, ...) \
    typedef ftype (*FNAME_CAT(func_, fname))(__VA_ARGS__); \
    ftype fname(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FUNCTION_END(ftype, fname) \
    void FNAME_CAT(fname, _end)() { }

#define FUNCTION_LENGTH(fname) \
    (int) ((intptr_t) FNAME_CAT(fname, _end) - (intptr_t) fname)

FUNCTION_START(void, test, int a, int b) {
    printf("a(%d), b(%d)\n", a, b);
} FUNCTION_END(void, test);

char* function_code(void* func, int flen) {
    return (char*) malloc(flen * sizeof(char));
}

void* function_create(const char* buffer, int blen) {
    void* func = mmap(0, blen, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
    return memcpy(func, buffer, blen);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* code = function_code((void*) test, FUNCTION_LENGTH(test));
    void* func = function_create((const char*) code, FUNCTION_LENGTH(test));

    ((func_test) test)(1, 2);
    ((func_test) func)(1, 2); // Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

    return 0;
}
```

**Debug output**

```
(gdb) p FUNCTION_LENGTH(test)
$2 = 42
(gdb) n
[New Thread 5920.0x282c]
a(1), b(2)
16ew Thr    ((func_test) func)(1, 2);
(gdb) s
0x000006ffffff0000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

Comment: Oh the humanity!  The macros aren't making the code any shorter, they're just hiding that you are doing (which is subtracting function pointers, that gives an unspecified result).

Comment: No, no, no, you didn't just tag this as C++, you didn't.

Comment: @DeiDei: The [tag:c++] tag might be correct, if this is being built using `-x c++` (default for the `g++` frontend) rather than `-x c` (default for the `gcc` frontend).

Comment: Just encrypt the entire executable.

Answer (score 6):

Your first problem is that you didn't ever actually use the `func` parameter to `function_code`... the code bytes from your indicated function never make it into the buffer.

But fixing that won't get you very far, because there's a big problem with your whole approach.  There's no guarantee made by either the C or C++ standard that functions are laid out in memory in the same sequence as they are in source code... in fact on any toolchain with any clue about optimization, they won't be.

I suggest you use the gcc-specific pragmas for placing functions in a particular code segment to separate the functions of interest, then store and strip that segment from the executable.  Perform your encryption/decryption on the entire segment as a unit instead of trying to find out where individual functions begin and end.

Do note that the unencrypted code will be available in memory where skilled reversers will surely find it.  Because you don't know what you're doing, you've probably already spent more time troubleshooting your function length code than a reverse engineer will spend getting to the decrypted bytes.  Runtime decryption of code is very common for packers, and your dynamic allocation with execute access is going to stand out like a bright beacon in `/proc/` *`pid`* `/maps`.

Comment: Furthermore, most modern operating systems prevent execution of code in data segments, as a security measure, by default. This is enforced by the operating system. This would be another major fail, here.

Comment: @Sam: This code isn't in a data segment, it's (intended to be) a dynamic allocation.  And he's specified `PROT_EXEC` in the `mmap` call.  Won't work on systems with W^X enforcement, really should use `mprotect` to change the protection bits after writing to the page.

Comment: Thanks for your response! We're aware that function placement is very specific to the toolchain, and that `gcc` with `-O0` will produce the expected result, at least with the version (5.4.0) we're using. Regarding reverse engineering, that would require that the content was first decrypted, which would require a valid license. This is a risk we're willing to accept, since the overall risk would still be mitigated. It's a software that's freely available to try out, but certain features are quite expensive.

Comment: @ThomasDoyle: If you don't plan to decrypt that portion of the code for the free version, why don't you just separate the restricted features into a separate shared object and not distribute that file in the free version?  That's a much better option than forever locking yourself into `-O0`.

Comment: @ThomasDoyle: Overall, the fact that you didn't use your debugger before posting to discover that the bytes in your buffer were very different from the ones at the function's original address makes me seriously question whether you have the skills to do this.

Comment: @BenVoigt, it's possible that you are right, and in that case I will go down a road that leads nowhere, hopefully learning something new which will help me make better decisions in the future. However, I do intend to go down that road, if nothing else, for the chance to learn.

Comment: @ThomasDoyle: Well, "execute code loaded into memory" has many applications such as JIT compilation, so it's good to learn.  Automatically extracting the bytes of your function at runtime, not so much.  Pull them out by hand using the usual debugging tools and give yourself a hard-coded array constant so you can move on to the interesting parts of page protection and relocatable code.